What do the Viewport options do in Super Mario Eclipse?
When starting up Super Mario Eclipse, a mod for Super Mario Sunshine, I was greeted with a settings menu. One of the settings under the "Better Sunshine Engine" category was Viewport with options for SMS, SM64, and SMG.
What do these viewport options do?

The viewport options change how the camera works to closer resemble Super Mario Sunshine (SMS), Super Mario 64 (SM64), or Super Mario Galaxy (SMG). It controls how close or far away the camera can get from mario and the angles it will point.
For example: when fully zoomed out, the SM64 option offers a fairly close up over-the-shoulder view, SMS gives a semi over-head view when zoomed out to maximum, and SMG moves the camera far behind mario to give a broad view. See the video below for a visual comparison.



